# Bash script returning syntax error: syntax error in expression (error token is...)

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I want to start a particular set of services (in the example below, the service is called users), and in my script, that is working.  However, I see the following error when running the command:

```
./services.sh: line 40: [[: start users: syntax error in expression (error token is "users")
```

I am calling this command using a `case` statement in my script, that looks for the `start` parameter:

```
case "$1" in
    (-h)
            display_help
            exit 0
            ;;
    (start)
            start_services "$@"
            ;;
```

My function for `start_services` is as follows:

```
start_services()
{
    # Check to see if there are any arguments, if not, start all services
    if [[ $@ -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo
            echo "Starting all services:"
            echo "======================"
            for svc in $services
            do
                    echo "     Starting the $svc service... "
                    $SVCPATH/bin/$svc &
            done

    else
            shift;
            echo
            for var in "$@"
            do
                    echo "Starting the $var service... "
                    $SVCPATH/bin/$var & > /dev/null
            done
    fi
}
```

So, the failure is occurring at this line, line 40:

```
if [[ $@ -eq 0 ]]; then
```

As I mentioned, the script is doing what I want, but I keep getting the syntax expression error.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean `$#` rather than `$@`?

Comment: The issue is the incorrect construct used for checking the argument which need to be `$#`. The error you are seeing is because of unquoted `$@` causing incorrect number of operands to `[[` operator. Always use `$((..))` for arithmetic context i.e. `if (( $# == 2))`

Comment: I don't see a closing `esac` in your first code block, typo or error? ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

`$@` seems to contain your services names, but in `if` you try to count them. Use `$#` instead of `$@`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if [[ -z "$@" ]]
```

---

1. `-z`: check for none zero string; faster than counting how many items there